# Api base url from grunt serve command using protractor in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, protractor, yeoman

I'm using [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) to setup my angularjs application and `grunt` as my task runner.

I trying to pass the base url of my api dynamically that is from the `grunt serve` command

Using [protractor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-runner) to pass the baseurl and my gruntfile is shown below:

```
grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    protractor: {
      options: {
        configFile: "node_modules/protractor/example/conf.js", // Default config file
        keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
        noColor: false, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
        args: {
          baseUrl: grunt.option('baseUrl', 'http://localhost:80/')
        }
      },
      your_target: {   // Grunt requires at least one target to run so you can simply put 'all: {}' here too.
        options: {
          configFile: "e2e.conf.js", // Target-specific config file
          args: {} // Target-specific arguments
        }
      },
    },


 ....
   }
```

`grunt serve protractor --baseUrl=http://localhost:8080`

How to get the baseurl to the service which is passed as a parameter from above command?